# Custom sort the array

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

You have a set of numbers. `a1, a2, a3, a4, ..., an`. The numbers are random and may repeat.

Arrange the number in order such that `x1 > x2 < x3 > x4 < x5 > x6 ...`.

`x1` has no relationship with `x3, x4, x5, ...`, `x2` has no relationship with `x4, x5,...`, `x3` has no relation ship with `x1, x5, x6,...` and so on.

There maybe many feasible solutions to this problem see that the final answer reaches any one of them. If the input is like `22,22,22` then it should output a message as "no feasible solution", but for an input like `7 7 7 3 3` it should print out a solution like : `7 3 7 3 7`.

My solution is first sort input array by O(nlogn) and fill the output array alternatively fist with last most untouched element and then with first untouched element So overall O(nlogn). Can we do it better and how to track non feasible solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: well any type of hint is appreciated

Comment: @OlivierLi which point you want me to focus , please be clear ?

Comment: Your formatting could be clearer and it would be helpful if you gave the code to your solution to prove you got something working. Also, the "Can we do it better" is vague. How do you determine better? Code simplicity,computational complexity, space complexity or more?

Comment: @OlivierLi Ok , i say i didn't got "something working" , i assume asking question does not require this , well doing better is off course and "obviously"  asking about complexity(time and space) since i gave my complecxity , and no code was asked , anyone can code idea , and last i think my question understandable enough

Comment: To answer the question if we can do better: the solution 2,1,3,2 will not be found by your suggested algorithm, if I understand it correctly (it would attempt 3,1,2,2 which is invalid). I don't see an obvious, more complete, solution (other than, say, iterating through all permutations and rejecting ones that don't work).

Comment: A funny question, +1 for originality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You obviously exclude equality. For all equal items can't be arranged this way. So, if something is equal to the current end of the ready sequence, we'll throw it off.

  1. take a1,a2. Someone of them is greater. That will be the first one.
  2. Now we need the greater item, than the last one. If the next a is greater that the last x, let the a become the next x. If next a is smaller than the last x, put the current a on the last x place and the x move to the next position.
  3. The same as 2, only change larger for smaller and vice versa.
  4. return to 2.
  5. Exit on the ending of input array a.

     a: 7,10,5,8,9

     x: 10,7     ?5

     x: 10,5,7     ?8

     x: 10,5,8,7     ?9

     x: 10,5,8,7,9

The complexity is O(n). But you shouldn't forget to clean off the equal items. You can get random and throw off the equal to the previous number simultaneously with the choosing the next a item. You needn't create the array of a. They are random anyway.